# OS X SSH connect to host operation timed out

Tags: ssh, osx-snow-leopard

When running

```
ssh -v myuser@xx.xxx.xxx.xx
```

I connect to the server and can operate the session

When running

```
ssh myuser@xx.xxx.xxx.xx
```

the behaviour returns

```
ssh: connect to host xx.xxx.xxx.xx port 22: Operation timed out
```

THis behaviour appeared after I stated on the server:

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

thus adding the id to the agent has messed up ssh...  How to fix?

Comment: fuctionality came back after a few more than on machine re-boot.